# test react-native reanimated with useDeriveValue

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have a component that gets a goBack function as a param

the component effector animation (with react-native-reanimated-2) when the user press on any button,

after the animation is finished I call to goBack function.

I track on `isOpen` value with `useDeriveValue` of `ract-native-reanimated-2`

I need to make a test on this component to check that the function is called,

code on my button onClick

```
 useDerivedValue(() => {
    if (isOpen === 0) {
      runOnJS(toGoBack)();
    }
  }, [isOpen]);

  const toCloseWiteAnim = () => {
    isOpen.value = withTiming(0);
  };
```

but with this code my test pass

```
 const toCloseWiteAnim = () => {
    isOpen.value = withTiming(0, {}, (isAnimFinished) => {
      if (isAnimFinished) {
        runOnJS(toGoBack)();
      }
    });
  };
```

```
  const element = await queryByTestId('test.x-icon');
  expect(element).toBeTruthy();
  fireEvent.press(element);
  expect(mockedGoBack).toBeCalled();
```

How can do that?

Comment: Have you looked at jest.useFakeTimers and the related calls?

Comment: yes,but my problem isn't solved by that